# Does Jackson2 provide something similar to JAX-B's Marshaller/Unmarshaller Listener?

Tags: jaxb, jackson

I have a need in certain cases to alter the serialized/deserialized value while marshalling/unmarshalling JSON using Jackson2.

Does there exist a mechanism similar to javax.xml.bind.Unmarhsaller.Listener/javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.Listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There have been requests for post-processing hooks, esp. for deserialization, but no implementation yet.

Jackson 2.2 will come with `Converter` annotation (`@JsonSerialize(converter=MyConverter.class)`, `@JsonDeserialize(converter=...)`) which could perhaps be used for similar purpose. This is similar to JAXB `XmlJavaAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks @StaxMan - more or less what I was looking for. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ok good. 2.2 isn't out yet (it has been delayed by wanting to add bit more JAX-RS improvements in), but latest snapshots should work, or building locally. And release should not be too far out (couple of weeks).

Comment: I'm not even sure at this point I need the functionality - getting some flack from a co-worker about content and without mashing through gobs of model classes this would be a boon to detect certain types and modify on the fly.